# How can i hide a column in a gridview dynamically using C#?

Tags: c#, gridview

Is there a way that i can hide a column ( or some columns ) in a gridView dynamically?

Comment: Have you tried `grid.Columns[0].Visible = false;` ??

Comment: @yogi:yes that was the correct thing to do.
(i was trying to use CurrentCell to achive this and thats why i was getting errors.:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably have to assign some values to the clicks or events so that when they happen you can write something like this:

```
GridView1.Columns[YouEventValue].Visible = false;
```

Where YourEventValue is a variable that is assigned a number based on what event just happened.